# Platform dependent state of mt19937 in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, random

I want to save the state of the std::mt19937 random number generator in a C++ program, so that I am able to resume my program at a later stage at the same "randomness state". I also want to use my program on different platforms (Linux and Mac).

Consider the following minimal example where I simply write the current state to stdout:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

static mt19937 rng;

int main() {
  seed_seq seeder{1234};
  rng = mt19937(seeder);

  cout << "mt1: " << rng() << endl;
  cout << "mt2: " << rng() << endl;

  cout.imbue(locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
  cout << rng << endl;
}
```

My problem is that this generates different outputs for the state, depending on the platform I compile this. On a Linux system (g++ 7.1.0) I get:

```
mt1: 2684129121
mt2: 3957864051
3,598,990,873 2,041,003,246 [...]
```

while on my Mac (Apple LLVM 8.1.0) I get:

```
mt1: 2684129121
mt2: 3957864051 
1,413,537,266 1,230,536,264 [...]
```

Basically I want to understand why the states are different and how I can achieve that they are the same so that I can save and load the state between systems.

This question is related to this one:
[C++ std::mt19937 and rng state save/load & portability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727012/c-stdmt19937-and-rng-state-save-load-portability) However, the thread does not answer my question. It gave the hint of using the same locale, but that does not seem to affect the state.

Comment: I don't believe the standard specifies the exact details of the RNG's state. They are left to the implementation. You cannot portably transfer it between implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the specifics of how the classes are implemented is up to the compiler/platform, you're really not going to achieve what you're looking for with the STL.

If you want a consistent implementation, then I'd recommend looking at using Boost. It has an implementation of all the Random classes that are STL-compatible. (It also has some advantages over the STL, such as allowing `boost::random::random_device` to be used as a seed sequence). You can also make your own implementation of the class, though Boost is an existing, cross-platform implementation that you can use.

**EDIT:**

I wanted to revisit this answer and update it with some more accurate information. At the time I wrote the original answer, I was under the assumption that the standard didn't dictate how `operator<<` and `operator>>` worked for the various engines, and that's why it wasn't portable. I've since spent some time reading the standard (draft) documentation for the `<random>` header, and learned this is actually incorrect. The standard specifies the "textual representation" of the state of all the generators included in the standard library, and the iostream operators are defined based on that. The issue is actually that libstdc++ (the standard library implementation for GCC and sometimes Clang) doesn't implement the standard correctly in this regard. [There is an open ticket for the issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60441), but it's unlikely to be fixed anytime soon.

The challenge with implementing the iostream operators is that `mersenne_twister_engine`'s textual representation shifts all the values over one with each call to `operator()`. This requires using something like a circular buffer to store the state. libstdc++ tries to optimize this by calculating the changes to the state in `state_size` chunks. The problem with this method is that the engine doesn't directly store all the values required for the iostream operators most of the time. To work around this issue, libstdc++ opts to instead just output its actual internal state (`state_size` state values, followed by the "current index" in the state) instead of what the standard requires.

There are a number of ways that libstdc++ could fix their implementation to correctly implement the standard, with pretty much all of them being used by other implementations. It could double the storage used for the engine to keep enough data to always have the values needed for the iostream operators like [Microsoft's STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/random). It could remove the bulk state update and instead update it once for each call to `operator()` like [LLVM's libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__random/mersenne_twister_engine.h). It could also implement a "rewind" function to compute the values required for the iostream operators when needed like [Boost.Random](https://github.com/boostorg/random/blob/develop/include/boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp) (which increases the computational cost of not just the iostream operators, but also `operator==`). All of these changes have associated trade-offs, and any such change will probably have to go through some sort of transistion plan to avoid causing too many issues with backwards compatibility. Because of this, it may be a while before it *does* get fixed, even though there are many ways it *can* be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the only alternative is to use another library.